# Selenium : Selecting an item from unordered list by name of the item

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-lists

I have a html code as that has :

- A division: consists of a button and unordered list
- Clicking on button displays values of list
- Each list element has a check box so that multiple values could be selected from the list
- Each list name is denoted inside -li and -a tags {-a- class="ng-binding">0< -a-}

I want to select an element by the value of  tag i.e. 50 (here)

Code I am using :

```
pageDropDown.click(); // to view the list element
pageList.click(); // to select the list
pageList.findElement(By.linkText("50")).click(); // to select the element
```

I have also tried List< WebElement > but that doesn't work for name of the item

Error I am getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"50"}
```

My Question is:

How can I select multiple values from an unordered list by the value of the item in the list and not by xpath or the indexvalue.

Comment: I mean by the name of the item

Answer (score 0):

The selenium webdriver is going to fast, you will have to wait some few milisecond that the browser display your list.
You can do that with the WebDriverWait :

```
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, MAX_WAIT_TIME)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                @Override
        public Boolean apply(final WebDriver d) {
            pageList.findElement(By.linkText("50")).click(); // to select the element
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: That is not necessarily true, you cannot pinpoint that as the problem without more evidence.

Comment: Agree... I was a little too rapid in my answer... But the wait for an element to appear is a very recurrent problem

Comment: But I am getting the same error even after implementing explicit wait.

Comment: Could you activate thé feature to take screenshot when error in order to see if the component youre trying To access is realy displayed ?

Comment: I could see the list has been displayed, but the item is not getting selected.
I believe i am not able to select the item from the list on the basis of By.linkText 
Could you help with an alternative way to select the by the value of < a > tag

Comment: Could you past your full <a> tag please

Comment: <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" style="max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="Analyst">
Analyst
</label>
</a>
</li>

Comment: All I could do is 
'List<WebElement> liList = driver
                    .findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='contentdiv']/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div/ul"));'
liList.get(3).click();

I would like to know how to select the item by its name